# In Rails, how does one associated objects are up-to-date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback, associations

Consider:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blue_children
  has_many :red_children
end

class BlueChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

class RedChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  validate :parent_cannot_have_blue_children

  def parent_cannot_have_blue_children
    unless parent.blue_children.empty?
      errors.add(:parent, 'has blue children')
    end
  end
end
```

For code like this:

```
def test
  p = Parent.create!
  # Much time passes, during which, perhaps, some far-off process adds
  # a blue child to p.
  p.red_children.create!
end
```

there is a risk that the validator sees an out-of-date version of parent. In particular, even if there appear to be no blue children in the validator, there may be one. I have checked the SQL logs to confirm that no query is done to reload parent or the `blue_children` association from the validator.

I can think of several ways to fix this:

- Keep a counter, in the database itself, of the number of blue children in `Parent`, atomically incremented/decremented as children are added, and check the counter instead of looking at the association itself. That would work, but at the expense of more complexity in the model, and more storage in the database.
- Add a `before_validation` hook to `RedChild` that reloads `Parent`. However, it would be very surprising to callers if saving a child object reset pending changes to the parent.
- Insist that callers who want to save a `RedChild` create a transaction, reload the `Parent` within the transaction, and then save the child so that the validator is guaranteed to be up-to-date. This would work, but is cumbersome, but would seem to violate the encapsulation of the child object.

At present, I'm leaning towards maintaining a counter in the database. Is there a better way?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  eg Postgres, Mysql etc

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You can do this at the database level which will prevent race conditions like in your problem.  http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Yes, that would certainly work as well -- and may be necessary in some cases -- but I would prefer to remain at the Rails level where possible.

Comment: I believe that with rails-level "existing record" validation you can only ever hope to minimise race conditions, but you can never eliminate them.  There will always be a finite time period between the select to check if a record exists and then going on to do your insert/update, during which time another process could write a record.  When you go live it is likely that you will have several worker processes, and the more workers you have, and the more requests they get, the greater the chance of this happening.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, thank you (belatedly) for your reply. I agree; the only solutions are acquiring database locks in the application to prevent races, or adding database triggers to reject invalid records. For example, in this case, if blue children updated their parent on creation, then locking the parent would work. And, as you say, database triggers will also work. Thank you!

Comment: If you use database locks/triggers then make sure you use transactions in your Rails code, to handle the database failure gracefully http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) in the validation: it will trigger a new SQL request to check if blue children exists:

```
class RedChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  validate :parent_cannot_have_blue_children

  def parent_cannot_have_blue_children
    if BlueChild.exists?(parent: self.parent)
      errors.add(:parent, 'has blue children')
    end
  end
end
```

This way the validation is always up to date.

Comment: That certainly works. It's unfortunate that it doesn't go through the model objects directly, but it successfully contains implementation details within the model (i.e., users of the model don't need to create transactions).